# Match all locations that responses with 404 error on Nginx

Tags: nginx

I am porting a compiled CGI from IIS to Nginx, the app makes use of custom error 404 to perform Url rewriting and static file caching, in IIS this works

```
    <httpErrors>
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/index.exe" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

It passes the request_uri to index.exe and then something like this

example.com/users

is processed internally as

example.com/index.exe?module=users

or something like

example.com/blog/my-first-post.html

is processed as

example.com/index.exe?module=blog&postname=my-first-post

In Nginx I am trying this (the cgi running at background on another server)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root E:/domains/example.com;
    index index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;
    location ~* ^\/.* {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
    }
}
```

But if I enters example.com/users I get a 403 error...

Please any help will be gratefully :)

Comment: Take a look at `http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page` will that meet your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code did the magic

```
  server {
  listen 80;
  server_name julcar.net.ec;
  root D:/Domains/julcar.net.ec/root;
  index index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;
  autoindex on;
  location = / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
  }
  location ~ ^\/.+ {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      error_page 404 = @julcar.net.ec;
  }
  location @julcar.net.ec {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:5001?404=$request_uri;
  }
```

Now it passes 404 errors just like IIS and is very easy to take them in the CGI.